# Hello gurus, Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my JSON syntax string?

Tags: json

I am POSTing this to a URL but the other side is only picking up the last K+ LabResultItem. Here is my JSON string:

```
"LabResultItems": [
   {
    "LabResultItem": {
     "AnalyteName": "pH",
     "Result": "7.4",
     "Units": "mmHg"
     },
    "LabResultItem": {"
     "AnalyteName": "pO2",
     "Result": "31.0",
     "Units": "mmHg"
     },
    "LabResultItem": {
     "AnalyteName": "pCO2",
     "Result": "33.4",
     "Units": "mmHg"
     },
    "LabResultItem": {
     "AnalyteName": "K+",
     "Result": "42.0",
     "Units": "mmHg"
     }
   }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: If there is an answer below that has helped you, please don't forget to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

please try the one below

```
{
  "LabResultItems": [
    {
      "AnalyteName": "pH",
      "Result": "7.4",
      "Units": "mmHg"
    },
    {
      "AnalyteName": "pO2",
      "Result": "31.0",
      "Units": "mmHg"
    },
    {
      "AnalyteName": "pCO2",
      "Result": "33.4",
      "Units": "mmHg"
    },
    {
      "AnalyteName": "K+",
      "Result": "42.0",
      "Units": "mmHg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This definitely worked. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

`"key": value` structures must be contained within `{ ... }` in order to form a dictionary/object, but `"LabResultItems": ...` is not.  You need to wrap your near-JSON in `{` and `}`.